# Insert(add) / Delete(Remove) multiple rows and columns left or right or up or down using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm trying to insert number of rows and number columns to the table using JQuery. After adding rows and columns I need to add one or more column or row in that previous added table. With specific cell it may be left of the cell or right of the cell or up of the cell or down of the cell.

For example: Imagine a table like below structure.

```
Row : 3 , Column : 3  Add (button)
```

**Generated Table :**

```
 R/C  C1   C2  C3
 R1   v1   v2  v3
 R2   v4   v5  v6
 R3   v7   v8  v9
```

This is my table: After generated my table, I wish to add one column after C2

**Then the expected output table**

```
 R/C  C1   C2  C3  C4
 R1   v1   v2  0   v3
 R2   v4   v5  0   v6
 R3   v7   v8  0   v9
```

Like wise Row after R2..etc..

I have tried the code for creating tables

[Link Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mprRb/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function creates your column at runtime:

```
 function addColumn(currentColumn,afterOrBefore)
 {
  var allRows=$('table').find('tr');
   $.each(allRows,function(index,value){
         var cells=$(value).find('td');
         if(afterOrBefore=='before')
                 {
              $('<td>0</td>').insertBefore($(cells[currentColumn]));
              }
           else
            {
               $('<td>0</td>').insertAfter($(cells[currentColumn]));
    }
   });
 }
```

and this is for creating rows:

```
 function addRow(currentRow,afterOrBefore)
  {
    var allRows=$('table').find('tr');
        var rowText="";
          for(i=0;i<$(allRows[0]).find('td').length;i++)
              rowText+="<td>0</td>";
        if(afterOrBefore=='before')
                   {
                $('<tr>'+rowText+'</tr>').insertBefore($(allRows[currentRow]));
                }
            else
              {
                 $('<tr>'+rowText+'</tr>').insertAfter($(allRows[currentRow]));
 }
 }
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mprRb/585/)

Hope this will help you..